# For every object x, A is equivalent to A cross {x}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What I did was defined a function $f: A \rightarrow A  \cup ${x}$ $ by $f(a) = (a,x)$ for each $a\in A$. And I got stuck on how to start on dealing with the showing of 1-1 and onto with this kind of function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $f: A \to A \times \{x\}$?

Comment: Yes. That was typo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't conflate $ A \times \{x\} $ with $ A \cup \{x\} $.

Can you describe every element of $ A \times \{x\} $? The result should follow quite fast from that.

Comment: Oh yes. But I was confused on starting with the showing of 1-1 and onto with the function :((

Comment: Try writing out what each element of $ A \times \{ x \} $ looks like. See if you can find some $ a $ such that $ f(a) $ is equal to that element.